# Alternative for https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/<video_id>?v=2

Tags: youtube-api, http-status-code-410

These days I noticed that Youtube API which I'm using on my project is no longer available, e.g.

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/dLEk9yiXVQs?v=2

returns HTTP 410 response code which means that requested resource is no longer available and will not be available again.

What should I use instead?

Comment: This API is still working but needs appropriate X-GData-Device Authorization Header.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly then you should be using `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=<video_id>&key=<YOUR_API_KEY>&part=snippet` from now on.

[Google shutdown the old API effective April 20th, 2015.](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6098135?hl=en)

Take a look at the newest v3 API [getting started](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started).

Comment: somehow it is working and for some of the video it is not, because i have tried my own video  with video caption,  `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/captions?part=snippet&videoId=h2pWeot3MJY&key=AIzaS******************`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this link with your Youtube channel id after the = and it should work.

https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id= your youtube channel id number

Comment: That's a 404, now.