# YouTube APIs V2 Any alternatives?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I implemented a code to get some data points for some videos as I'm working in a research company.

Actually for the sake of simplicity I used 
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/{$videoID}?v=2&alt=json it was working one or two months ago. But now it doesn't work.

Is it true? if yes any alternatives?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternative for https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/<video\_id>?v=2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30685625/alternative-for-https-gdata-youtube-com-feeds-api-videos-video-idv-2)

Answer (score 1):

The Youtube API V2 has been deprecated and will no longer return results. You must use the new V3 to get the videos. You will be able to accomplish what you're looking for using this new method (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list)